# Radio Button shows checked being false, but was clicked on. Why?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, radio-button, checked

Issue: Checked attribute on radio buttons indicates false, but I had clicked on them before clicking the submit button.
Conditions: Databound RadioButtons are receiving correct data from sql stored procedure in order to display correct values next to radio buttons. RadioButtons are within a ListView that is within a table. I’m having to do this as RadioButtons as opposed to a RadioButtonList as I need to group each pair of fields that come from the stored procedure together as opposed to grouping the actual fields together so as to force the user to choose between one of the two field in every row. When the user clicks on the submit button, which is located outside of the ListView, but within the Table, processing goes to a JavaScript function that checks each row for validate that one of the buttons was checked. 
Findings so far: When setting a breakpoint in the JavaScript function, I found that both of the checked values were false, even though I had clicked one of them on.

CODE

.aspx file

```
    <table style="border: 1pt solid #6666FF; width: auto; font-family: Verdana; border-collapse: collapse; 
       background-color: transparent; align-content:center; margin:auto" >
    <!-- 
        Title: Pick 'Em for Week #
    --->
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <asp:Label ID="PickEmTitle" style="font-size:large;" runat="server" Text="Pick 'Em Contest" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Overdue" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="The time for choosing your teams has expired for this week. Play PickEm again next week."></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="NotAllPicked" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Not all choices have been made. Please choose for all games, then submit your entry."></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--- break in table ---->
    </tr>

<!--      
    Display 16 AA games
        Date     Home Team  Radio Button     Away Team  Radio Button
        - OnRadioButtonClick 
            CS code will store choice in cookie
--->

    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right; font-size: medium; align-content:center;">
            <asp:ListView ID="ListViewPickEm" runat="server">
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="color: white; background-color: forestgreen; border: groove; width: 100%;">
                        <td style="float:left;">
                            <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="GameID" Value=<%# Eval("GameID") %> runat="server" />
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="HomeTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HomeTeamName") %>'  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HomeID" Value=<%# Eval("HomeTeamID") %> runat="server" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonHome" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonHome_CheckedChanged" />                            </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="AwayTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AwayTeamName") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="AwayID" Value=<%# Eval("AwayTeamID") %> runat="server" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonAway" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonAway_CheckedChanged" />
                        </td>                        </tr>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
                        <tr>
                            <td>No data was returned.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="color: white; background-color: darkgreen; border: groove; width:100%;">
                        <td style="float:left;">
                            <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="GameID" Value=<%# Eval("GameID") %> runat="server" />
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="HomeTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HomeTeamName") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HomeID" Value=<%# Eval("HomeTeamID") %> runat="server" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonHome" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonHome_CheckedChanged" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="AwayTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AwayTeamName") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="AwayID" Value=<%# Eval("AwayTeamID") %> runat="server" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonAway" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonAway_CheckedChanged" />
                        </td>                        </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                                        <th id="Th1" runat="server">Date</th>
                                        <th style="float: right;" id="Th2" runat="server">Home Team</th>
                                        <th id="Th3" runat="server"></th>
                                        <th style="float:right;" id="Th4" runat="server">Away Team</th>
                                        <th id="Th5" runat="server"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                            <td id="Td2" runat="server" style=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="float:left;">
                            <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="GameID" Value=<%# Eval("GameID") %> runat="server" />
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="HomeTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HomeTeamName") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HomeIDvalue" Value=<%# Eval("HomeTeamID") %> runat="server" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonHome" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice"  OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonHome_CheckedChanged" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="AwayTeamNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AwayTeamName") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="AwayIDvalue" Value=<%# Eval("AwayTeamID") %> runat="server" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonAway" runat="server" GroupName="GameChoice" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonAway_CheckedChanged" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>


<!-- 
    Submit Button
--->


            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="PickEmGames" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FollowingHSFootballConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="GetWeeklyGames" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="onPickEmSubmit" Height="30px" style="margin-left: 0px" Width="100px" />


        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function AllPickEmGamesSelected(visible)
    {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            var HomeTeamVerif = document.getElementById("FeaturedContent_ListViewPickEm_RadioButtonHome_" + i).checked;
            var AwayTeamVerif = document.getElementById("FeaturedContent_ListViewPickEm_RadioButtonAway_" + i).checked;
            if (!HomeTeamVerif & !AwayTeamVerif)
            {
                visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    function ReverseButton()
    {
        if (document.getElementById(
    }

    function IdentifyChosenTeam(RBHomestr, RBAwaystr, ValueID) 
    {
        if (document.getElementById(RBHomestr).checked == true)
        {
            ValueID = "HomeID_";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById(RBAwaystr).checked == true)
        {
            ValueID = "AwayID_"; 
        }
        else
        {
            ValueID = "";
        } 
    }

</script>
```

C# file

```
    protected void onPickEmSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //        Will ensure deadline time has not passed
    string dateTime = "08/25/2016 13:00:00.00";
    DateTime CutoffDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
    DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
    if (localDate > CutoffDate)
    {
        // if deadline has passed, will send error message
        Overdue.Visible = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        //        Will ensure all games were picked
        //            else send an error message back
        Boolean visible = false;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Page)this, base.GetType(), "AllPickEmGamesSelected" + DateTime.Now,
                                             string.Format("AllPickEmGamesSelected('{0}');", visible), true);
        NotAllPicked.Visible = visible;
        //        Will get values from hidden fields to database and save
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            string RadioHomeIDstr = "FeaturedContent_ListViewPickEm_RadioButtonHome_" + i;
            string RadioAwayIDstr = "FeaturedContent_ListViewPickEm_RadioButtonAway_" + i;
            string ValueID = "";
            int[] TeamIDint = new int[16];
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((Page)this, base.GetType(), "IdentifyChosenTeam" + DateTime.Now,
                                             string.Format("IdentifyChosenTeam('{0}','{1}','{2}');", RadioHomeIDstr, RadioAwayIDstr, ValueID), true);

            if (ValueID == "")
            {
                NotAllPicked.Visible = true;
                break;
            }
            else
```

:
:
:

Comment: Which event are you using to populate the checked? the reason i ask is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx it is very easy to use the wrong event and wipe the data before the post back is handled

Comment: When you say 'populate the checked', do I also need to set the checked attribute to true within a function that is called when utilizing the 'onCheckedChanged' attribute? I assumed the radiobutton automatically set the changed attribute when clicked.

Comment: @MikeT - Having asked the above question, I am reading the link and making a determination of what part of the life cycle the process is in when clicking on the Submit button. Not sure if clicking on the radio or submit button is causing a change in state.

Comment: Have you considered doing the javascript function on the server-side instead?

Comment: Yea, if I'm not mistaken the submit button is going to cause a postback which could be resetting the state of the radio button.

Comment: @MDDeVane, the point i was checking is that if you use the code behind to set the default values in the wrong event then you could be overwriting the values with the database (or other source) values before you read what you changed them to

Comment: @MikeT - I don't see that I am setting any default values in the C# code behind. On the LoadPage, I am populating the data that the radio button text and other fields that are accessed by the radio button table that is displayed, but I am not populating any checked field with a default value. Thank You, though.